# How do I add items inside a static box while using Sizers?

Tags: text, button, wxpython, border, sizer

I'm using wx.Python and have a group of objects that I want 'wrapped' within a static box similar to this:

[image]

However that [tutorial uses position sizes](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#wx.StaticBox), and I'm using sizers instead.  I'm having a hard time getting the items inside:

[image]

but rather they're below the static box.  How do I include the objects within the static box using Sizers and not position?

Here's my code:

```
    # Date and Graph Type Selection 

    self.dateLbl = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, 'Date Range:', size=(240, 140))
    self.dategraphSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.dateLbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.LEFT, 5)

    # Date Range Selection
    self.dateSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.dateone = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.datetwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.date2Lbl = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "TO")
    self.dateSizer.Add(self.dateone, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 2)
    self.dateSizer.Add(self.date2Lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 2)
    self.dateSizer.Add(self.datetwo, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 2)


    # Date Quick Selection Buttons
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.dateSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    self.todayButton = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Today Only')
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.todayButton, 0, wx.ALL|wx.LEFT, 5)
    self.recentButton = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Most Recent Session')
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.recentButton, 0, wx.ALL|wx.LEFT, 5)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using Sizers, you have to create a specific 'Static Box Sizer' that is a Sizer and contains the Static Box you want to use.  This is done by:

```
self.foo = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box, wx.ORIENT)
```

This means that your Static Box needs to be created beforehand and is an arguement passed to the creation of the Sizer.  From there on, the Sizer behaves exactly like a regular Sizer.  This is what I got fixing your code:

```
    # Date and Graph Type Selection 

    self.dateLbl = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, 'Date Range:', size=(240, 140))
    self.dategraphSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.dateLbl, wx.VERTICAL)
    #self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.dateLbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.LEFT, 5) NOTE THIS ISN'T NEEDED ANYMORE

    # Date Range Selection
    self.dateSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.dateone = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.datetwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.date2Lbl = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "TO")
    self.dateSizer.Add(self.dateone, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 2)
    self.dateSizer.Add(self.date2Lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 2)
    self.dateSizer.Add(self.datetwo, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 2)


    # Date Quick Selection Buttons
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.dateSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    self.todayButton = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Today Only')
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.todayButton, 0, wx.ALL|wx.LEFT, 5)
    self.recentButton = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Most Recent Session')
    self.dategraphSizer.Add(self.recentButton, 0, wx.ALL|wx.LEFT, 5)
```

Which yields this result:

[image]

Comment: Good job for finding it out yourself :-)